# limit of nth root of a difference

Tags: calculus, limits

I need some help finding the limit of the following sequence (as n goes to infinity):

$$a_n=\sqrt[n]{7^n-3^n}$$

I can limit it from above by $\sqrt[n]{7^n}$ but i can't see a way to limit it from below by anything that converges to 7.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: If you divide it by $7$, what do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all $0 < x < 1$ and $n > 1$ we have $x < \sqrt[n]{x} < 1$. Putting $x = 1 - (3/7)^n$ gives the result you want.

Comment: thanks a lot, that explained it well :)

Answer (score 2):

Since
$$3^n=_\infty o\left(7^n\right)$$
so
$$\sqrt[n]{7^n-3^n}\sim_\infty\sqrt[n]{7^n}=7$$